# nasm calling subroutine from another file

Tags: nasm, subroutine

I'm doing a project that attaches a subroutine that I wrote to a main file included by the teacher.  He gave us the instructions for making our subroutine global but apparently I'm an idiot.  The two asm files are in the same folder, I'm using `nasm -f elf -g prt_dec.asm` and `ld prt_dec` and then doing the same for main.asm. Here's the relevant code in the main.asm:

```
    SECTION .text                   ; Code section.
global  _start                  ; let loader see entry point
extern  prt_dec

_start:
mov     ebx, 17
mov     edx, 214123
mov     edi, 2223187809
mov     ebp, 1555544444


mov     eax, dword 0x0
call    prt_dec
call    prt_lf
```

The line `call    prt_dec` throws "undefined reference to prt_dec" when i use `ld main.o`

Here's the a code segment from my prt_dec.asm:

```
    Section .text
    global prt_dec
    global _start

start:
prt_dec:
      (pushing some stuff)
L1_top:
(code continues)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to call a routine in another asm file or object file?
if you are Assembling prt_dec.asm and are linking multiple asm files to use in your main program, here is a sample, 2 asm files Assembled and linked together... *** NOTE *** `hello.asm` ***DOES NOT *** have a start label!

Main asm file: hellothere.asm

```
sys_exit    equ 1

extern Hello 
global _start 

section .text
_start:
    call    Hello

    mov     eax, sys_exit
    xor     ebx, ebx
    int     80H
```

Second asm file: hello.asm

```
sys_write   equ 4
stdout      equ 1

global Hello

section .data
szHello     db  "Hello", 10
Hello_Len   equ ($ - szHello)

section .text
Hello:
        mov     edx, Hello_Len
        mov     ecx, szHello
        mov     eax, sys_write
        mov     ebx, stdout
        int     80H   
    ret
```

makefile:

```
APP = hellothere

$(APP): $(APP).o hello.o
    ld -o $(APP) $(APP).o hello.o

$(APP).o: $(APP).asm 
    nasm -f elf $(APP).asm 

hello.o: hello.asm
    nasm -f elf hello.asm
```

Now, if you just want to separate your code into multiple asm files, you can include them into your main source: with `%include "asmfile.asm"` at the beginning of your main source file and just assemble and link your main file.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the problem was my method of assembling the files.

Comment: Thank you `%include "asmfile.asm" ` is what I needed. The hardest part about assembly is the lack of documentation.