# Placing subroutines in separate files in arm assembly using the keil IDE

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, keil

I am new to ARM Assembly programming using Keil 4, I have been trying to assemble two subroutines in assembly files. One of the subroutines calls the other.

Calling (Branching) a subroutine placed within the same file works, but, if one subroutine is placed in a separate file the following error message comes up

`file2.s(8): error: A1163E: Unknown opcode SUBROUTE , expecting opcode or Macro`

The code is appended below

**FILE 1**
;; Directives
         PRESERVE8
         THUMB
         UNIFIED

```
      AREA    RESET, DATA, READONLY
      EXPORT  __Vectors
      __Vectors 
      DCD  0x20001000     ; stack pointer value when stack is empty
      DCD  Reset_Handler  ; reset vector
      ALIGN

    AREA    MYCODE, CODE, READONLY
    IMPORT SUBROUTE 
    ENTRY
    EXPORT Reset_Handler 
    Reset_Handler

                 MOV R1, #0x0A      ; Set loop counter
                 MOV R0,#00         ;intilaize resultant register

      loop1 CBZ R1,FINISH       ; if loop counter = 0 then exit the loop
      BL     SUBROUTE
      B loop1           ; next loop         
      FINISH    B FINISH            ; keep looping 
      END                   ; end of program
```

**FILE 2 :**

```
  AREA   subroutine, CODE, READONLY
          EXPORT SUBROUTE
 SUBROUTE   ADD R0,R1           ; Addition opertaion
            SUB R1, #1          ; loop counter decrement
            BX lr
            END
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15148730/3642162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armasm labels have to start in the first column.  Make sure there are no leading spaces/tabs before `SUBROUTE` and `FINISH` on the lines where they are defined.  On the other hand, directives (like `AREA` and `IMPORT`) must not start in the first column and must have some leading whitespace.

Comment: Thank You it was really time killing for me