# How to break down a NASM application into modules/packages and include them?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm starting to learn the Assembly language. I'm familiar with it in the basic level. I wonder, how big application in the Assembly are organized, that is, how can I split them into modules/packages and include them into other modules? I'm talking about NASM in particular.

Comment: (this is heavily opinion biased, so take with a grain of salt) Big assembly applications are usually organized as C++ applications, using Assembly only for few most critical parts. With a reasonably written C++ source the average quality of produced machine code will easily outperform hand written assembly, and the few critical parts are also easier to tune after the compiler had first go on them. So don't expect to find some highly sophisticated tools for big-asm-project management. Actually there are several, called C, C++, Java, C#, etc... ;)

Comment: @Ped7g, incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- **Use [`%include`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.6.1)**
  To include an external file into the current one.
  This can be further controlled with the [`-i`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.16) command line switch.

  You can also force NASM to pre-include a file using the [`-p`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.17) switch.
- **Assemble multiple files**
  Since NASM is not a linker, you can take advantage of the linkers' ability to... well, link files together.

  Use the [`GLOBAL`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.6) directive to make a set of symbols visible to other modules.
  Use the [`EXTERN`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5) directive to import a set of symbols from other modules.

  You can pass all the object files to the linker.
  NASM (as today) can only assemble one file at a time, so a build script is needed.

---

The two above are not mutually exclusive but you have to basically understand the [NASM output file formats](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) to see when the latter is applicable.

Comment: For an example of doing this with `global Hello` in one file and `extern Hello` in the other, see [nasm calling subroutine from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15148730) .  It works exactly the same for labels on data; NASM doesn't distinguish "code labels" from "variables".