# What causes "x.asm:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `y'"?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

For a long time I had not programmed with C and Assembler (about 2 years). Now I have decided to start again but I would like to do something much more complicated. I thought about creating a simple kernel. Now I found this source code on the internet:

boot.asm:

```
global loader
extern kernel_main
MAGIC equ 0xbad
FLAGS equ 0x3
CHECKSUM equ -(MAGIC+FLAGS)

section .text
align 4
dd MAGIC
dd FLAGS
dd CHECKSUM

loader:
call kernel_main
cli

quit:
hlt
jmp quit
```

kernel.c:

```
void print(char *text) {
    char *memory = (char*)0xb8000;
    while(*text) {
        *memory++ = *text++;
        *memory++ = 0x3;
    }
}

void kernel_main() {
    print("My cat sometimes smells like cafe. I love it.");
}
```

linker.ld:

```
ENTRY(loader)
SECTIONS {
      . = 0x100000;
      .text : { *(.text) }
}
```

Note: I compiled the C file with "GCC" and the Assembler file with "NASM".

If I try this command:

```
ld -T linker.ld -elf_i386 -o final.bin boot.o kernel.o
```

It says: "boot.asm:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `kernel_main'".
How can I fix this?
Im working on windows and do not want to run a VM with Linux or anything. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
This is my GCC command:

```
gcc -m32 -o kernel.o srckernel.c -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
```

This is my NASM command:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o boot.o boot.asm
```

Comment: `-elf_i386` should be `-melf_i386` if anything. Also show the `gcc` and `nasm `command lines. Note that mingw gcc might prepend a leading underscore to symbols so you might need `extern _kernel_main` and `call _kernel_main`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nasm calling subroutine from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148730/nasm-calling-subroutine-from-another-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong. I will assume given the error:

> boot.asm:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `kernel_main`

that you are not using an ELF cross compiler and that you are using a GCC compiler that generates native Windows executables (ie. Cygwin and MinGW). I highly recommend the use of an i686 (or x86_64) [ELF cross compiler](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler#Windows_Users) for OS Development especially on Windows.

Your primary problems are:

- The option `-elf_i386` was probably meant to be `-melf_i386` however that is even incorrect. With a GCC that targets windows you will want to use `-mi386pe` to output as Win32 PE/COFF format. The Windows GCC linker usually doesn't know how to generate ELF executables. I also recommend using the `-N` option when using LD to output i386pe format. Change your linker command to be:

  ```
  ld -N -T linker.ld -mi386pe -o final.bin boot.o kernel.o
  ```
- With Win32 PE/COFF objects<sup>1</sup>: functions that use the CDECL calling convention have to have an [underscore (`_`) prepended](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040108-00/?p=41163) to them. `kernel_main` needs to be `_kernel_main`. You need to change these lines in `boot.asm` from:

  ```
  extern kernel_main
  call kernel_main
  ```

  to:

  ```
  extern _kernel_main
  call _kernel_main
  ```
- You don't show how you compile `kernel.c` and how you assemble `boot.asm` but they should look similar to:

  ```
  nasm -f win32 boot.asm -o boot.o
  gcc -g -c -m32 -ffreestanding kernel.c -o kernel.o
  ```
- When you do manage to generate `final.bin` it is a Windows PE executable. The [Multiboot specification](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html) requires ELF executables. After linking to `final.bin` with LD, you can convert `final.bin` to ELF format with:

  ```
  objcopy -O elf32-i386 final.bin final.elf
  ```

  `final.elf` should now be usable as a Multiboot ELF executable.
- There is an issue with your Multiboot header in `boot.asm`. The Multiboot magic value is `0x1badb002` not `0xbad`. Since you haven't specified a video configuration in your Multiboot header `FLAGS` should not have Bit 1 set, `FLAGS` should be 0x1 instead of 0x3. Change your Multiboot header from:

  ```
  MAGIC equ 0xbad
  FLAGS equ 0x3
  ```

  to:

  ```
  MAGIC equ 0x1badb002
  FLAGS equ 0x1
  ```

---

With the changes noted above I was able to generate an ELF executable called `final.elf`. When run with QEMU using the command:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel final.elf
```

The output I get is:

[image]

---

### Footnotes:

- <sup>1</sup>The extra underscore on function names doesn't apply when generating Win64 PE32+ objects.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I expected as an answer.